# Using Twitter for user authentication in Heroku: "can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080"

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter

I am following [this scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-twitter) on twitter node authentication to authenticate users on a Heroku app. I have made my callback URL this: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/twitter/callback

I am able to click on a link to authenticate the user but then and it says "can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080"

No useful clues in the logs. I believe I have set up all my routes and .js files properly, as laid out in the tutorial, and am not sure what could be causing this problem.

Comment: I would guess you have to use port 80. I'm not really familiar with the node-twitter thing, but if the callback is executed in the browser you also have to change the URL to the Heroku app (yourapp.herokuapp.com).

Comment: Changing it worked! I can either close this or you can post your response as an answer.